# Remove duplicate hashes and set value depending on value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following array of hashes, and want to remove the ones that have duplicate :name values.

If ANY of the hashes have :enabled set to true for that :name, then :enabled to be true. Otherwise it should be false.

So, given this:

```
[{:name=>"one", :enabled=>true}, {:name=>"two", :enabled=>false}, {:name=>"one", :enabled=>true}, {:name=>"two", :enabled=>true}]
```

I want to end up with:

```
[{:name=>"one", :enabled=>true}, {:name=>"two", :enabled=>true}]
```

because :enabled is set to true in at least on of the hashes for both :name=>"one" and :name=>"two"

How can I do this?

Comment: are there only two elements in every hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of [`each_with_object`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001516) and [`map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001491) should get you there:

```
a.each_with_object({ }) { |e,h| h[e[:name]] ||= e[:enabled] }\
 .map { |k,v| { :name => k, :enabled => v } }
```

For example:

```
>> a = [{:name=>"one", :enabled=>true}, {:name=>"two", :enabled=>false}, {:name=>"one", :enabled=>true}, {:name=>"two", :enabled=>true}, {:name=>"three", :enabled=>false}]
=> [{:name=>"one", :enabled=>true}, {:name=>"two", :enabled=>false}, {:name=>"one", :enabled=>true}, {:name=>"two", :enabled=>true}, {:name=>"three", :enabled=>false}]
>> compressed = a.each_with_object({ }) { |e,h| h[e[:name]] ||= e[:enabled] }.map { |k,v| { :name => k, :enabled => v } }
=> [{:name=>"one", :enabled=>true}, {:name=>"two", :enabled=>true}, {:name=>"three", :enabled=>false}]
```

The `each_with_object` summarizes the `:name`/`:enabled` pairs in the little hashes while collapsing the booleans to `true` if any of them are true (for a given `:name`) and then the `map` unpacks the summary hash into hashes of the original form.

Comment: Damn, so great. Much better than mine! +1

Comment: @apneadiving: Pretty close though, you probably would have ended up with the same thing if you started with `each_with_object` instead of `inject`, the block's return value for `inject` complicates things and probably pushed you towards `merge` to avoid the nasty `; memo` bit at the end of the block. At least that's why I use `each_with_object` as my general purpose visitor.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I should really move from REE! :)

Answer (score 1):

For purposes of simplification, I'll assume that :enabled and :name are the only two elements in every hash.

```
original = [{:enabled=>true, :name=>"one"}, {:enabled=>false, :name=>"two"}, {:enabled=>true, :name=>"one"}, {:enabled=>true, :name=>"two"}]
```

Build a temporary hash to store this, and collapse the values.

```
new_hash = Hash.new(false)
list.each do |element|
    new_hash[element[:name]] ||= element[:enabled]
end
```

Finally, iterate over the hash to restore to original format.

```
new_array = []

new_hash.each_pair do |k, v|
    new_array << {:name => k, :enabled => v}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd have done:

```
inject({}){|memo, h| memo.merge({ h[:name] => (memo[:name] || h[:enabled])} )}.map{|k,v| {:name => k, :enabled => v } }
```

Comment: Worth knowing if you don't have 1.9 or Rails to give you `each_with_object`.